# Component in series with digital communication lines

Tags: audio, identification, dac

What is the component highlighted in picture?
Main IC in the picture is [PCM510xA](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/pcm5102a.pdf).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that looks like a resistor network. Basically four 33 Ohm resistors.

Comment: And that would make sense for back/source terminating thse lines.